# Loop through data query based on values entered in an Inputbox and UserForm

Tags: excel, loops, userform, inputbox, vba

I'm working on a script which will eventually loop through a data range currently on worksheet "Data." The criteria will be gained through an `Inputbox` (Date) and a `UserForm` (Environment) and with these results it will look for the date and environment in the query and paste any matching results to another worksheet (Applications)

This is what I have developed so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim NextRelease As Long
Set trelinfo = Sheets("TRELINFO")

If MsgBox("Would you like to promote the next release in batch?", vbQuestion _
+ vbYesNo, "Promote the next release?") = vbYes Then

NextRelease = CLng(CDate(InputBox("Please enter the date of the next _
release", "Next Release", "DD/MM/YYYY")))

Worksheets("Active or Review").Range("F4").Value = NextRelease

checkblank = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(trelinfo.Range("A2:A4"), _
NextRelease)

If checkblank <> 0 Then
    ReleaseDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NextRelease, _
trelinfo.Range("A2:A4"), 1, False)
End If

If NextRelease = ReleaseDate Then
Else
If MsgBox("Not a valid Release Date", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "No Release") _
= vbOK Then Exit Sub
End If

If MsgBox("The Daily Release Process will now pull in all iForms equal to _
" & (CDate(NextRelease)), vbOKOnly, "Move") = vbOK Then

Load FrmEnv
FrmEnv.Show
End If

End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that I have hit a road block, I am a complete novice with `InputBox` and `UserForms` and have no idea how I can use these values to loop through a range of data.

The `UserForm` has a `Combobox` which currently looks at a defined range

```
ComboEnv.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("Environment").RefersToRange)
```

I do not expect this script to be completed - as great as that would be, instead I would appreciate a tip on how I can use the values entered in the `UserForm` and `InputBox`to look through a range of data.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim rCell as range

for each rCell in Environment.Cells

'... code that checks for NextRelease variable

next rCell
```

Let me know if this helps out at all

Answer (score 0):

Store your 'Environment' as a variable after the combobox value has been selected, using `myEnvironment = ComboEnv.Value` in your userform code. Declare this as a public variable using `Public myEnvironment As String` in your workbook code.

Once the userform is closed, the code below your `FrmEnv.Show` should execute. You'll be able to use the NextRelease and myEnvironment variables from here to loop through your data.

Comment: I've declared NextRelease as a Public variable, although I'm not sure how this helps?
However when trying to declare `myEnvironment = ComboEnv.Value` I keep getting a 424 Object required error.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you! My understanding of VBA is still rather basic and I have never worked on UserForms before hence the challenge. I am placing myEnvironment after `frmEnv.show` - Please see above which is not in a module.

Comment: You won't be able to access the combobox from there. Do you have a button on your userform for the user to press once they’ve submitted their value(s)? If so, place your `myEnvironment = ComboEnv.Value` in the code which executes once the button is pressed (double click the button in design mode to locate this sub). Edit: In fact, also declare myEnvironment as a public variable beside your NextRelease declaration.

Comment: I'm going about this the wrong way. I've edited my answer, let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have now added the myEnvironment assignment to the submit button however after `Unload frmEnv` I have added a `msgbox` to This Workbook to see whether the variable is being recorded however it's blank. The 424 error is no longer present.

Comment: You will need to declare myEnvironment as a public variable in your workbook code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121783/discussion-between-rory-and-paul).

Comment: Despite adding `Public myEnvironment as String` i'm still getting a blank field. I have tried adding this to the `UserForm` and `ThisWorkbook` I don't understand how `NextRelease` works but `MyEnvironment` doesn't, sorry to be a pain.

Comment: I'm being prompted to "Please avoid extended discussions in comments." This conversation has been automatically moved to a chat, happy to continue there (see above link).